# NuGet pack – token replacement sometimes fails

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

I've had a terribly frustrating experience over the past couple of days trying to deploy continuous delivery for a specific project via TFS. The project is an internal library that has to be published on the private NuGet repo, so one of the steps is packing the nupkg files.

The problem I'm encountering now is that `nuget pack` complains about missing `Authors` and `Description` in some circumstances, while in others it doesn't. My AssemblyInfo.cs for the simplest project where it fails is as vanilla as they come:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("A.B.C")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Some description here")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company // Department")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("A.B.C")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("88888888-8888-8888-8888-888888888888")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1.0")]
```

I sanitized the values, but I kept the format of the actual values I'm using (e.g. instead of "A.B.C" we have "LibraryName.Module.Submodule").

The nuspec file is equally boring:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <!-- Mandatory, static stuff -->
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>

    <!-- Mandatory stuff you should review upon re-packaging -->
    <releaseNotes>The first internal release.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>

    <!-- Optional stuff you should only include if you need it -->

    <projectUrl>http://www.example.com/</projectUrl>
    <!-- <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl> -->
    <!-- <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl> -->
    <!-- <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags> -->
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When running `nuget pack` it sometimes fails with the infamous "***Authors is required; Description is required***". I've had success randomly, fiddling with things that should not affect the process, such as adding or removing dependencies, or moving the nuget binary around the filesystem. And yes, I did check, there were no `nuget.config` files anywhere along the path to the binary in all experiments – still, in some very carefully crafted setups it works, and in others it doesn't.

I currently have two servers in the agent pool; on one of them it works with nuget 4.6.2, and it doesn't work with 4.7.0. On the other it works with neither. When I hit a setup where it works, it works consistently every time I run the build – but right now I have one server that works and one that doesn't, and I'm totally stumped as to why this happens (and they're both consistent across builds).

I found a bug reporting that [token replacement fails](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5807) with the error I'm encountering for reasons pertaining to how AssemblyInfo.cs is formatted, but I don't think that's the case for my project – then again, I learned to expect anything.

Here's the full execution log:

```
C:\Program Files\nuget.4.6.2.exe pack "C:\TFS-Agent\_work\2\s\A.B.C\A.B.C.csproj" -OutputDirectory "C:\TFS-Agent\_work\2\s\publish" -Properties Configuration=release -Verbosity detailed
NuGet Version: 4.6.2.5055
Attempting to build package from 'A.B.C.csproj'.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
Packing files from 'C:\TFS-Agent\_work\2\s\A.B.C\bin\Release'.
Using 'A.B.C.nuspec' for metadata.
Authors is required.
Description is required.
System.Exception: Authors is required.
Description is required.
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.Validate(Manifest manifest)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ProcessNuspec(PackageBuilder builder, String basePath)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath, NuGetVersion version, String suffix, Boolean buildIfNeeded, PackageBuilder builder)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool nuget.4.6.2.exe
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeToolCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

The output up to the error is identical on the server where it works (i.e. up to and including `Using 'A.B.C.nuspec' for metadata.`). The only difference is that... well... it works.

Please let me know if you can suggest any directions I could investigate this further.

## Further details

- The agents are both version 2.112.0
- The server that works runs Windows Server 2012 R2 (Agent.OSVersion = 6.3.9600), the one that doesn't work runs Windows Server 2012 Standard (Agent.OSVersion = 6.2.9200)
- I tried copy/pasting the quasi-static Authors and Description from AssemblyInfo.cs to the nuspec files, but that breaks packet versioning (they all get generated with version 1.0.0). Updating the version in two places every time manually is not something I want to live with.
- As a temporary solution, I ended up constraining the build on the server that works, by adding a constraint on the Agent.OSVersion capability. I'm not liking this.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Is the build agent which works also with NuGet Version 4.6.2.5055? Try to run `nuget pack` with the **project file** rather than just the `.nuspec`, to see whether it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens.

Comment: The nuget binary is deployed during the build, so it's guaranteed to be the same. As you can see in the final output, nuget pack does target the csproj, not the nuspec (check out the actual command line at the very top of that fragment). I don't understand how the version of TFS might affect the way nuget behaves; are there any quirks in that area I should be aware of?

Comment: I want to know the TFS version to have a test on my side. Are your build agents the same version? You could try to delete folder %buildagnet%\_work to see how's the result?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.112.26307.0

I'm not sure the build agents are the same version, I installed them at least 6 months apart; how do I check the version? For the record, the one that works was installed earlier than the one that doesn't work. Purging _work didn't help. One notable difference between the servers is that one of them is Windows Server 2012 R2 (the one that works), while the other one is Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: You could check build agent version in Agent Queues--Capabilities. You are using TFS 2017.1, try to upgrade your TFS 2017 to latest TFS 2017.3.1, and have another try.

Comment: If nothing else comes out of this, I will try that as well. But I highly doubt this is in any way related to TFS or the TFS agent, because they end up triggering a vanilla CLI command, which nuget fails to execute. I strongly suspect this is a bug (or a misuse) related to nuget.exe, not something to do with TFS.

Comment: If you run nuget pack manually on the failed build agent machine, how's the result?

Comment: Exactly the same.

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to TFS since you have the same result when you use Nuget manually. You may try other versions of Nuget manually to see whether you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Are you populating any of the values in AssemblyInfo.cs dynamically? Or is it all static? And from what I understood the nuspec file is checked in and you are not generating it for each build right?

Comment: I did come across another issue and I was able to reproduce it, Nuget doesnt always throw the "System.Exception: Authors is required." when the authors field is missing. It could be stemming from something else, for example here adding the "AssemblyInformationalVersion" throws that error

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5548

Comment: Both AssemblyInfo.cs and the nuspec files are 100% static, and they are formatted the way I have illustrated in the OP. Yes, I know about that bug, but it's unrelated – notice that my AssemblyInfo.cs does not include any atypical elements.

Comment: I took the Nuget code from Github and debugged the heck out of it over the weekend but I was not able to replicate this issue with my test project. So either you will have to send me a zip of your project (with sensitive information removed) but I really would like to see the dependency chain/Dlls. Or on your 4.6.2 agent if you VS installed on your agents, you could get the Nuget code and the try debugging it.

Comment: Thanks, I think debugging the thing on site is probably the best approach. I'll try that when I get a chance; right now I'm deep into a couple of other projects, and I really can't squeeze this in.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I had to include the Description element in csproj and set to a value. This doc was helpful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets

Answer (score 0):

We have a build definition in Azure Devops that has a custom powershell build step which modified the AssemblyInfo.cs file before building based on a variable in the build definition. We use it to tab the version of the package as Alpha, Beta, etc.

I was getting this same error and only needed not put underscores in that variable when queuing the build.